# Why static method cannot make values change unless I return the values

Tags: java, static, static-methods

I learned static method today, and I am confused about how values change inside the static method. 
When I write static method like this

```
public class test{
public static int printInt(int t,int n){
System.out.println(t);
t= t + n;
return n;
}
}
```

and call it in main

```
public class Method {
public static int i;
public static int m;
public static void main(String[] args){
    i = 5;
    m = 6;

    test.printInt(i,m);
    System.out.println(i);
}
}
```

the t do not change as I suppose to.
If the static method only make change into values that you return?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The term `static` in simplest terms denotes something that belongs to the class. In the above code method `printInt` belongs to the class `test` and not to a specific instance of this class.

In the main method which is in another class `Method` you are trying to pass local variables `i` and `m` as parameters and due to that copy of them will be passed to method `printInt`. You make changes to copy and not actual arguments. So changes will not be reflected in the main method.

Note: Use camel-case and other standard coding conventions in Java. Also naming a class `Method` is a bad idea.

Comment: So how can I really want to make it reflect in the main method? Thanks!